# New column with two comparisons before

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am working in a Excel table. This is the info that I have:

```
A B C D
At  ID  ID  ID
At  ID  ID  ID
At  ID  ID  ID
At  ID  DESC    ID
Ag  ID  ID  ID
Ag  ID  ID  ID
Ag  ID  ID  ID
Ag  ID  ID  DESC
B   ID  ID  ID
B   ID  ID  ID
C   ID - DESC   ID - DESC   ID - DESC
C   ID - DESC   ID - DESC   ID - DESC
C   ID - DESC   ID - DESC   ID - DESC
CS  ID  ID  ID
CS  ID  ID  ID
Ca  ID - DESC   ID - DESC   ID - DESC
Ca  ID  ID  ID
Ca  ID  ID  ID
Ca  ID  ID  ID
Ce  ID  ID  ID
Ce  ID  ID  ID
Ce  ID  ID  ID
Ce  ID  ID  DESC
Ce  ID  ID  DESC
```

I want to create a new column with this conditions previously. Firstly, I want to get all the info that it has equals names. Then, there are to compare, by rows, the following columns, B C and D. For that, if they are all the same, it would 1 on it, otherwise 0.

This is an example.

First, we have At in the column A. We get all the info.

```
At  ID  ID  ID
At  ID  ID  ID
At  ID  ID  ID
At  ID  DESC    ID
```

Then, we have to compare, B2=B3, B2=B4, B3=B4. Same thing with the others columns. How the value of B4 is distinct of other, then in the new column E, it would be a 0.

Other example. For value "B" in column A. We get all the info:

```
B   ID  ID  ID
B   ID  ID  ID
```

As they are all the same, in the new column E it would be a 1.

How can I do that? I need it to be done with the simplest functions, if possible, such as VLOOKUP.

This is the output that I want:

```
A B C D E
At  ID  ID  ID 0
At  ID  ID  ID 0
At  ID  ID  ID 0
At  ID  DESC    ID 0
B   ID  ID  ID 1
B   ID  ID  ID 1
```

I did that:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A;$A$2;B:B;$B$2;C:C;$C$2;D:D;$D$2)>1; "Yes"; "No")
```

But I get all values as "Yes". What I am doing wrong?

Best regard.

Comment: Looks like you want to count **unique values** in a range. If the count is 1 means all values are the same so column E = 0, else 1. If you have Excel 365 check functions UNIQUE and FILTER

Comment: But, how can I do that in the formula?

Answer (score 1):

If you have Excel 365 you can use this formula:

```
=IF(ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER(tblData[[A]:[D]],[A]=[@A])))=1,"yes","no")
```

It counts the unique rows per Column A value - if there is only one unique row it is a valid section.
[image]

Comment: what is tblData ? Can you do that instead of 0 and 1, put No and Yes, respectively..? @Ike

Comment: tblData is the name of data table (via Insert > tbl), regarding yes/no: I updated the formula

Comment: it doesn't work the formula that you provided me.., I get an error in ````tblData[[A]:]````. What's happening?

Comment: did you create the table and named it tblData? Sorry, there was a double "=" at the beginning

Comment: yes, but I named like Table1. I get the error there..

Comment: Then you have to adjust the formula - using Table1 instead of tblData